# Why is Tensorflow always automatically installed?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a virtual environment in which I installed Tensorflow-gpu, since I installed the dependencies as follows:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And in my requirements.txt, I had the following listed:

```
tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1
```

and when I use "pip freeze" to check after I executed the above command, I see that only tensorflow-gpu is installed, which is correct.

However, when I run:

"pip install -e ."

from my project's local directory, it shows all other dependencies are already satisfied, which is correct, since I already installed as above, except that it also is installing "tensorflow", which is not listed in the requirements.txt.

Now if I ran 'pip freeze' again, I can see that both are installed:

```
tensorboard==1.13.1
tensorflow==1.13.1
tensorflow-estimator==1.13.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1
```

"tensorflow=1.13.1" isn't listed in the requirements.txt, but why is it added after I ran 'pip install -e .'? I don't want it to be installed.

Comment: mby because it is part of tensorflow-gpu, be happy about the smart pip

Answer (score -1):

Because tensorflow is one of the packages listed in requirements.txt or one of the packages in requirements.txt depends on it, pip will see package1 in requirement.txt and installs all other packages it may depend on then second one's dependencies and so on.

Comment: First, tensorflow isn't listed in requirement.txt. Second, if one of the packages depends on it, why it doesn't show up when I ran "pip install -r requirement.txt". It is only installed when I run "pip install -e .".